# Wigner's Friend - cosmic consciousness

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedingers-cat

I was looking into Schrodinger's cat and encountered this fun interpretation of it, called Wigner's friend.

It basically states that if the observer of the cat-observer A-is also placed in a room, then observer A's superposition state of either alive or dead will need to be collapsed by another observer, observer B, outside of that room, and if observer B is also in a room that encloses the room in which observer A is, then observer C will be required to collapse the superposition of observer B to see if he is dead or alive, and this chain goes on until there is a cosmic consciousness that determines everyone's superposition.

What I'm not sure about is if this is the original version of Wigner's friend that Wigner himself came up with, as Wigner's friend experiment that I know of is quite different from the one above. The one that I learned about deals with the polarization of a photon that is either vertical or horizontal, and that even if the superposition collapsed for the observer in the room, the superposition remains for the observer outside the room until he learns about the result from the observer in the room.

So did Wigner himself come up with Wigner's friend shown above involving cosmic consciousness or is it a variant interpretation of Wigner's friend experiment by other scientists?

Also, is this cosmic consciousness theory even feasible, or is it a completely lunatic idea?